# How do i copy bone data to a bone of different name?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'd like to copy a pose from one rig to another rig with different bone names. For example, in the first rig, bone y has loc/rot/scale values and i want to copy the loc/rot/scale values to bone x in the second rig. It should basically be a list, that the data of every bone in rig A is copied to another bone in rig B. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The problem is that there's no way for Blender to establish which bone in B corresponds to some particular bone in A.  You can copy transforms one by one with a simple ctrl-c, ctrl-v, or by copy/pasting keyframes.  But if you want to do it with everything at once, you need to tell Blender how these correspond.  (And the most direct way to tell Blender that is to rename the bones.)

Comment: sounds like "retargeting". You can write a script with a mapping to copy the transformations. There are also several add-ons that already do this. Here is one https://github.com/nkeeline/Keemap-Blender-Rig-ReTargeting-Addon for example. There was one that allowed you to do the mapping in the nodes editor but I can't remember its name :-(

Comment: ... I think it was [ReNim  - Node-Based Retarget Animation](https://blenderartists.org/t/renim-node-based-retarget-animation/1261958/1) but I have no clue if it still works in Blender 3.x. Here is another one: https://github.com/Mwni/blender-animation-retargeting

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Meanwhile, I did some more research and Rokoko is supposed to retarget any armature. The same product can do motion capture with a special suit.